# How to change a timestamp with timezone to date (YYYY)

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to change an entire columns format into a smaller date format.  I'm currently using PostgreSQL and need to change it from [timestamp with timezone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkC3D.png) to an easier format, preferably one that just displays the year?  How can I get this done?

Ive tried using to_char functions as well as date_parse to no avail.  Im still very new to this so its stumping me at this point, any help is much appreciated

Wed Dec 31 2008 19:00:00 GMT -0500 (Eastern Time Zone) is the current format.

I just want to be able to turn that into the year, so 2008

Comment: If you just want to _display_ the value differently, use: `to_char(the_column, 'YYYY')`

Comment: That's a year, not a date. It's not an easier format, it's a completely different value. You can use `EXTRACT()` or `DATE_PART` to extract the year from a date

Comment: Why do you want this? It matters. If you want to group by year for example, trying to group by the result of `EXTRACT` will have to scan the entire table to calculate the year, then filter or group by it. In such cases it's better to convert the query into a range query or use a calendar table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I need to make two columns for a school assignment, breaking down sales in 2012 and 2013.  It seemed like breaking this timestamp down into years would be easier to get the question answered.  Thanks

Comment: Using `EXTRACT(YEAR ...)` is the quick but very slow way so it's never used in production. The server has to read every single row to calculate the year. If you have a large table, this can quickly get very slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that you're dealing with `text`, it's best to convert it to an actual `timestamptz` first, using [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE). Then you can alter the column, casting it in place: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9KzC04-q)

```sql
create table your_table(invoicedate text);
insert into your_table values 
('Wed Dec 31 2008 19:00:00 GMT -0500 (Eastern Time Zone)');

alter table your_table
   alter column invoicedate
   type timestamptz using 
   (to_timestamp(invoicedate,'Dy Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS AAA TZHTZM'));

alter table your_table
   add column invoiceyear smallint;
update your_table set invoiceyear=extract(year from invoicedate);
```

Already mentioned [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) can get you the year out of a `timestamptz`.

Keep in mind that PostgreSQL will consume the timestamps and keep them internally as UTC. This means that if you want to process invoices differently based on their timezone of origin, you'll have to save that origin information in a separate column. Right now, extracting a year from that timestamp will give you 2009 instead of 2008, because that time in EST corresponds to 2009 in UTC. To get it as 2008, you'll have to read it as `invoicedate at time zone 'EST'`

Comment: thanks this worked.  Also thanks to everyone else that pitched in

Comment: A word of caution. You generally should not use `'EST'`, or any other timezone abbreviation. Instead use the full name '`US/Eastern'` or `'Canada/Eastern'` as appropriate. Timezone abbreviations are always  fixed offsets from UTC (EST is -05:00) thus do NOT adjust for daily savings time. On the other hand  the full name does adjust. Especially since the US Congress has/is considering year round DST.

Comment: @Belayer It doesn't seem to be the case. See [v10 demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9lQ5LeGW) vs [v9.6 demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vAmLGx4q). Back in 9.6 neither the abbreviation nor the full name accounted for DST. Starting from version 10 they both do. Please update the demo if I'm misunderstanding this and you mean some other behaviour.

Comment: Appears so but from the [v15 documentatio](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES). *A time zone abbreviation, for example PST. Such a specification merely defines a particular offset from UTC, in contrast to full time zone names which can imply a set of daylight savings transition rules as well.*  The exact phase exists in v9.6 through v15.